trino select from iceberg tables in Minio not working
I'm writing data from Kafka to Minio using the Confluent Iceberg sink. The catalog is a REST catalog.
I can see the tables in the catalog:
trino> show tables from iceberg.callcenter;
    Table
-------------
 calldetails
 calls
 customers

I see the columns of a table:
trino> describe iceberg.callcenter.customers;
   Column   |  Type   | Extra | Comment
------------+---------+-------+---------
 customerid | bigint  |       |
 name       | varchar |       |
 address    | varchar |       |
 membership | varchar |       |
 class      | varchar |       |
(5 rows)

But when I want to query the tables I get the following message:
trino> select customerid, name, address from iceberg.callcenter.customers;
Query 20240926_181431_00023_dx4ne failed: Error processing metadata for table callcenter.customers

I don't understand the problem here

the problem seems to be: No factory for location: s3://warehouse/callcenter/calls/metadata/00039-9f850882-fbf9-4fb7-86fe-93cd43ad70e1.metadata.json but the file exists!!!

I bumped into the same error: Query 20241025_033411_00038_anghg failed: Error processing metadata for table com.joyent.demo.books, how did you resolve it? Thanks
